# Bool doesn't change when colliding with an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I am making a game in C# Unity. I have this problem when in a collision event, everything else happens but not changing the value of the bool variable. The game is 2D and the collision event does occur, it's just that one line with the boolean that doesn't work. I've tried  to make it public to see if it changes even of a second and it doesn't change at all. The IEnumerators for waiting are just for the sound effect and when to close the mouth, so they play no part. Here is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SizeScaling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera mainCamera;
    private Vector3 scale;

    private AudioSource mergeSFX;
    
    public GameObject openMouth;
    public GameObject closedMouth;

    public bool mouth = false;

    void Start()
    {
        mergeSFX = mainCamera.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        scale = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        openMouth.SetActive(!mouth);
        closedMouth.SetActive(mouth);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Down")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            mergeObject(1);
        }
        else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Up")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            mergeObject(3);
        }
        else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Left")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            mergeObject(0);
        }
        else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Right")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            mergeObject(2);
        }
        StartCoroutine(close());
        mouth = false;
    }

    void mergeObject(int addDirection)
    {
        PlayerMover.direction[addDirection]++;
        openMouth.transform.localScale += scale;
        closedMouth.transform.localScale += scale;
        mergeSFX.Play();
        mouth = true; // Doesn't execute line
        StartCoroutine(wait());
    }

    IEnumerator wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    }

    IEnumerator close()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this line of code executes, but then you assign it to `false`.
First, the `mergeObject(...)` method assigns variable to `true` after collision, when `if` statements executes. However, after that you assign this value to `false` on these lines.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
     //after all if statements
     StartCoroutine(close());
     mouth = false;
}
```

It is not clear what you want to do with this variable, but the changes in code below should probably fix your issue.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Down")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        mergeObject(1);
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Up")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        mergeObject(3);
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Left")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        mergeObject(0);
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Right")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        mergeObject(2);
    } else {
        mouth = false;
    }
    StartCoroutine(close());
}
```

Comment: I know I set it to false, but it should set it to false after 3 seconds, I don't understand why it sets it to false immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, just moved where the bool is set to false in to the IEnumerator and it now works, no idea why, but it does.

```cs
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Down")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            mergeObject(1);
        }
        else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Up")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            mergeObject(3);
        }
        else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Left")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            mergeObject(0);
        }
        else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Right")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            mergeObject(2);
        }
        StartCoroutine(wait());
    }

    void mergeObject(int addDirection)
    {
        PlayerMover.direction[addDirection]++;
        openMouth.transform.localScale += scale;
        closedMouth.transform.localScale += scale;
        mergeSFX.Play();
        mouth = true;
    }

    IEnumerator wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        mouth = false;
    }
```